# What can I use as an alternative to yad's notification + menu in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, notification, gnome-shell-extension, yad

I have some scripts that use [yad](https://github.com/v1cont/yad)'s [notification + menu](https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/NotificationIcon/). It is ideal for my purposes.

Unfortunately, the notification uses a discontinued method that no longer works in Gnome 42 on Ubuntu 22.04 — the icon isn't displayed, and so the menu is unavailable. (Everything else in yad works correctly.)

The intended workarounds, [AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) or [TopIconsFix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1674/topiconsfix/), don't work (the icon isn't displayed).

There's a marvellous replacement, [Argos](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/), which, as might have you guessed, doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04; it's marked as incompatible.

So…

Do you know what I can use as an alternative to yad's notification + menu? Unfortunately, the only programming "language" that I know is Bash.

Thank you

Comment: What about zenity? Could it do what you need, or is it too simple or clumsy? (I'm using zenity in mkusb because it is available in most places including updates for new versions.)

Comment: Topicons+ is reported to work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1243830/558158, but it may be good to consider moving away from these tray icons.

Comment: @sudodus — Zenity doesn't have a notification + menu system, otherwise it would have been an ideal replacement.

Comment: @vanadium — I agree, yad should move away. I've raised a bug report, but I've heard nothing back, so I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @vanadium — TopIcons Plus works in 20.04, but not in 22.04, where it's marked as "incompatible".